# Is there a purpose for reveal between window jamb and casing (other than aesthetics)?

Tags: windows, trim

Hopefully this question is answerable. When making up window trim, there is typically a small reveal between the jamb and the casing. Is there a reason for having this, other than aesthetics / tradition?

Possible things that came to my mind, but I don't know if these are valid: easier to install, easier to hide imperfections.

I found this image that should clarify which pieces I'm talking about - jamb and trim/casing.
[image]

Comment: When you say “jamb”, do you mean “frame of window” or “framing for window”? (I understand the casing to be the window trim.)

Comment: @LeeSam I added an image to clarify. Casing == trim. Jamb == frame between the window and the inside edge of the wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flush joints are both challenging to achieve perfectly, especially where several come together, and are generally ugly. A seam in a flat surface looks odd, as though something was added on due to poor planning.

It's that simple.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging the difficulty in aligning two pieces of wood perfectly. Look at the Craftsman Style. They just piled on layers of trim to make everything “appear” planned out.